# Unix Sed Command - How to insert Control A (^A) in end of line

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to use `sed` to append the "^A" control character at the end of each line:

```
sed -i 's/$/^A/' testfile
```

I want the '\001' special character instead of the "^A" literal string.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\x01` for `^A` i.e.:

```
sed -i.bak 's/$/\x01/' file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i 's/$/^A/' file
```

when you press the `^A`, just press in this way: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+(<kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> together)

Comment: Sure that works, but I thought the OP wanted to get rid of the "live" Ctrl-A in the sed command. Besides, such things don't copy & paste well. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/$/'$'\01''/' testfile
```

#### Explanation

- `s/$/`    — start the sed argument
- `$'\01'`   — let bash expand this
- `'/'`      — end the sed argument

(I recommend you start off without the rather dangerous `-i` flag and only add it once you're sure it does what you want.)